# Text Output Error in VSCode on running Flutter App

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Newbie here, please be gentle. I have been attempting to build an app in Flutter and periodically testing it either in an emulator or on my phone (samsung galaxy A22). Today, I connect my phone, click 'Start Debugging' and get gibberish in the debug console in VSCode. I don't see the app appearing on my device.[VScode editor with gibberish text in debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRn1e.png)

I know I will have some debugging of my app to do, but I wasn't expecting bugs in the debugger. We live, we learn.

I have tried the usual, restart both devices and VSCode, run flutter doctor, flutter clean, ensured developer mode is enabled on phone, tried multiple USB-C cables. Any thoughts?

Comment: Found solution, I needed to reset the lineheight in the debug console, in settings - user - features - debug - console: line height.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, I needed to reset the lineheight in the debug console, in settings - user - features - debug - console: line height